# Alternative flows based on condition for akka stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Have a stream with custom flows and at a certain stage I want to split the stream and have two alternative data handling which will merge again later.

E.g.

```
                  -> F3 -> F6 
Src -> F1 -> F2                > Merge -> Sink 
                  -> F4 -> F5
```

`F2` should have a condition saying if data contains format `A` then it should go to flow `F3`, else go to `F4`.

As far as I can see, each flow can only have one port in each direction (or two if bidi) - so how can I support such a flow?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `Broadcast` to split the stream, then you will able to use `filter` or `collect` on each of streams to filter required data.

```
val split = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

Src -> F1 -> split -> filterCondA -> F3 -> F6 -> Merge -> Sink
                   -> filterCondB -> F4 -> F5 -> Merge
```

Also, there is `Partition` stage which handles the number of output ports and the map function from value to port number `f: T => Int`.

```
val portMapper(value: T): Int = value match {
  case CondA => 0
  case CondB => 1
}

val split = builder.add(Partition[T](2, portMapper))

Src -> F1 -> split -> F3 -> F6 -> Merge -> Sink
             split -> F4 -> F5 -> Merge
```

Maybe there is some simpler way.

Comment: Thank you, you save my day. We can create val filterCondA = Flow[Int].filter ()